# Switch unintentional loop

Tags: c++

So when I select lets say option 1 first. So Active Directory and then select option 3 Add user to group. It asks for the username. So that is okay. But when I enter the user name it then loops over and over displaying the menu instead of prompting for the group to add them to. I haven't touched C++ in ages and I never got intensely good. But just looking for some advice. Maybe even a better menu system.

```
void ActiveDirectoryMenu()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "\n1. Active Directory clean up\n2. Copy over use permissions";
        cout << "\n3. Add user to group\n4. Reset user password\n5. Enable - Disable account\n";
        cin >> tempChoice;

        switch (tempChoice) {
            case 1:
                ActiveDirectoryCleanUp();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Execute copy";
                break;
            case 3:
                ActiveDirectoryAddGroup();
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Specify username: ";
                cin >> tempUser;
                cout << "\nDefault password: ";
                cin >> temp;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Specify username: ";
                cin >> tempUser;
                cout << "\n1. Enable\n2. Disable\n";
                cin >> tempChoice;
        }
    }
    while (tempChoice != 6);
}
void ExchangeMenu()
{

}
void ActiveDirectoryCleanUp()
{
    cout << "Executing AD clean up....";
}
void ActiveDirectoryAddGroup()
{
    cout << "Specify user: ";
    cin >> tempUser;

    if (tempUser == "") {
        cout << "\nSpecify group: ";
        cin >> tempGroup;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter valid user" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see any reason for the infinite loop you speak of -- you're prompting for input in the third line of the loop body, so it should at least pause there. Make sure you are checking your input; you can never be certain that a user is going to be entering a number instead of a bunch of characters (or that they'll never mistype a number and accidentally add a character to the end)

Comment: The loop will run as long the user doesn't type in `6` after having performed an action formerly selected from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
  if (tempUser != "") {
```

instead of

```
  if (tempUser == "") {
```

I assume, you are checking here if user name is entered is not `""`. If "" then prompt for invalid name.

Comment: While probably correct, this won't explain the behavior described by the OP though! (should be a comment may be)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ infact it does.. read this sentence carefully _But when I enter the user name it then loops over and over displaying the menu instead of prompting for the group to add them to_

So that is only possible when username is not "".

Comment: I've been going through again, you're right! That's a pretty badly asked question :/ .

Comment: @GibsonJunk Does this fixes your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're only asking for the group if tempuser == "".  I suspect you intended to test if tempuser is NOT equal to "".